# Python Code runs in VS Code but not discord host site

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have written a discord bot in python in VS code. The code consists of 1 **init**.py file, and 9 Cog files.

example of my **init**.py:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild_count = 0
    
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        if guild.id == 941021482144903178:
            guild_count += 1

            for jsonguild in guilds["guilds"]:
                if jsonguild["id"] == str(guild.id):
                    break
            else:
                guilds["guilds"].append({
                    "id": str(guild.id),
                    "prefix": "!",
                    "tornapikey": "",
                    "tornapikey2": "",
                    "tornapikey3": ""
                })
                dbutils.write("guilds", guilds)

            if str(guild.id) not in aractions:
                aractions[guild.id] = {
                    "lastscan": 0,
                    "requests": []
                }
                dbutils.write("armory", aractions)

            for member in guild.members:
                if str(member.id) in users:
                    continue
                if member.bot:
                    continue
                users[member.id] = {
                    "tornid": "",
                    "tornapikey": "",
                    "generaluse": False
                }
                dbutils.write("users", users)

    print(f'Bot is in {guild_count} guilds.')
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')

    await bot.add_cog(admin.Admin(botlogger, bot, client))
```

example of admin.py:

```
class Admin(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, logger, bot, client):
        self.logger = logger
        self.bot = bot
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def config(self, ctx, arg=None, value=None):
        '''
        Returns the current configuration of the bot
        '''

        if not check_admin(ctx.message.author) and dbutils.get_superuser() != ctx.message.author.id:
            embed = discord.Embed()
            embed.title = "Permission Denied"
            embed.description = f'This command requires {ctx.message.author.name} to be an Administrator. ' \
                                f'This interaction has been logged.'
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            self.logger.warning(f'{ctx.message.author.name} has attempted to run config, but is not an Administrator')
            return None

        embed = discord.Embed()

        if not value:
            embed.title = "Value Error"
            embed.description = "A value must be passed"
        elif arg == "key":
            data = dbutils.read("guilds")

            for guild in data["guilds"]:
                if guild["id"] == str(ctx.guild.id):
                    guild["tornapikey"] = str(value)

            dbutils.write("guilds", data)
            self.logger.info(f'{ctx.message.author.name} has set the primary Torn API Key.')
            embed.title = "Torn API Key"
            embed.description = f'The Torn API key for the primary faction has been set by {ctx.message.author.name}.'
            await ctx.message.delete()
        elif arg == "key2":
            data = dbutils.read("guilds")

            for guild in data["guilds"]:
                if guild["id"] == str(ctx.guild.id):
                    guild["tornapikey2"] = str(value)

            dbutils.write("guilds", data)
            self.logger.info(f'{ctx.message.author.name} has set the secondary Torn API Key.')
            embed.title = "Torn API Key"
            embed.description = f'The Torn API key for the secondary faction has been set by {ctx.message.author.name}.'
            await ctx.message.delete()
        elif arg == "key3":
            data = dbutils.read("guilds")

            for guild in data["guilds"]:
                if guild["id"] == str(ctx.guild.id):
                    guild["tornapikey3"] = str(value)

            dbutils.write("guilds", data)
            self.logger.info(f'{ctx.message.author.name} has set the secondary Torn API Key.')
            embed.title = "Torn API Key"
            embed.description = f'The Torn API key for the secondary faction has been set by {ctx.message.author.name}.'
            await ctx.message.delete()
        else:
            embed.title = "Configuration"
            embed.description = "This key is not a valid configuration key."

        if embed is not None:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

These codes run perfectly in VS code, connects to Discord and all of the commands work as they should. When I try and run them on my Discord Bot Hosting Server (Something.Host) I get the following error with no code changes:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "__init__.py", line 85, in on_ready
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
    await bot.add_cog(admin.Admin(botlogger, bot, client))
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled numerous packages. My python verion on VS is 3.10.7, and on the server it is python 3.10x.

I have also tried adding this in admin.py

```
async def setup(logger, bot, client):
 await bot.add_cog(Admin(logger, bot, client))
```

and this in **init**.py

```
files = ['admin']
for cogs in files:
  bot.load_extension(cogs)
```

but this didn't work either.

Please could you help me find out why my Cog is returning a NoneType in my server, but not in VS code?

My bot logged a whole bunch of DEBUG stuff when trying to run, will try and provide a link to the file

Comment: bot.load_extension is async in dpy2.0. It is a coroutine method now

Comment: Your server is running an outdated version of dpy